# Using Keys as Values in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

So, we have an API that spits out:

```
{
    "2013-12-13": [subobject1, subobject2, subobjects3],
    "2013-12-14": [subobject4, subobject5],
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure, though, how to parse things in RestKit where the key changes dynamically.
I'd probably like to parse it into a list of objects that have a date, and the list of subobjects.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a mapping something like:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[XXX class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"date"];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"(date)": @"values"
}];
```

Where your `XXX` class has properties for `date` (`NSDate`) and `values` (`NSArray`).

Comment: Ah, that seems like exactly what I was hoping existed. Thanks!